# underscore template is removed from the DOM so can't be re-used

Tags: backbone.js, javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to use a simple inline underscore.js template with backbone, and pulling the template from a `<script>` tag via jQuery's `html()` method.

The page is supposed to render multiple Recipe callouts for each returned by the Recipe Model. It works on the first thumbnail, but on the second, it seems the `<script>` tag has been removed from the DOM, so underscore fails to render it and bails with `str is null on line 913`

For the template, I have

```
  <script type="text/html" id="user-recipe-rated-template">
    <div class="user-recipe-rated">
      <a class="thumb" href="<%= href %>"></a>
      <p><%= title %></p>
    </div>
  </script>
```

And the backbone view looks like:

```
var UserRecipeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function() {
        this.template = _.template($("#user-recipe-rated-template").html());
    },

    render : function()
    {
        this.el = this.template({
            title: this.model.get("Title"),
            href: '#'+this.model.get('UserContentId'),
            image_src: this.model.get('ThumbnailSrc')
        });
        return this;
    }
});
```

So, what I am seeing is that `$("#user-recipe-rated-template")` exists on the first thumbnail and all is well. On the second, it returns an empty array and underscore can't proceed.

I've trying memoizing the string of html and such, and that might work, but it seems there should be a cleaner way of doing this. What am I doing wrong?

(I'd like to use templates inlined as opposed to external JST for now to keep things simple - it seems nicer to have the template embedded in the page near where it will be loaded when the data comes in)

Comment: I see no reason why that script tag should disappear. Are you sure you aren't accidentally overwriting its containing dom element or something at some point?

Comment: That is what I thought as well.  Check to be sure you aren't overriding the .html() of that div on the page somewhere. The code posted looks correct. Watch that div and see where it empties, maybe there is some init code or iterating code that is clearing the div.

Comment: yep you guys were right on. There was some code (not mine :) that emptied the container before rendering the view. So it also emptied the template

Comment: Thanks - I had the same error, except in my case I had defined the template in my html file, but I was including the javascript <script> before my template, hence when I tried to get the **$('#myid).html()**, it didn't exist yet, and returning a null string.

Comment: Another thing, if you are going to use the same template for many multiple views, it may  pay to initialize it once and then either just use that in each views render method, or you can assign a reference to it in the initialize method of the view.

Comment: Also I don't think is good idea to explicit assign `View.el` to anything like in here: `this.el = this.template({ ... })`, you should do something like: `this.$el.append( this.template({ ... }) )`.